# Access Form Listbox Header Labels Not Saving?

Tags: ms-access, listbox, label, columnheader

I have a simple listbox on a lookup form. I have it's Column Heads property set to yes.  The listbox has a query rowsource.  I have the fields set up, in the rowsource with 
label1:field1 
[label 2 nice]:field2 
[label 3 nice]:field3 
(etc) 

I save it, I save the form. I go to form view, and all looks good.  i close the form and test things on other forms. I end up back on that form, and the listbox shows the headers as 
field1 
field2 
field3 
(etc)

If I go back to design view, back to the rowsource query, the labels are still there.  If I save and go back out, they are good again.

Anyone want to help me stop pulling my hair out?

Comment: The first thing I usually check is that I have no other code changing the rowsource of that box to something that doesn't have those labels.

Comment: you are a genius. I am a moron.  I do change the row source in my code, and wasn't even thinking of that.  Can you post this as an answer, so I can give you credit? lol

Comment: Hey, I just thought I'd check, 'cause it has happened to me before :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to check is that there is no other code changing the rowsource of that box to something else. It can be very easy to forget to change all places that set the rowSource or recordSource of a field or form, after you add a field, or change labels.

Comment: I found out something else (from another old post I found somewhere). If you have a form in datasheet view, changing the column widths won't generally save.  You have to go to layout view, and then adjust the columns.  Then you have to select the columns and bold and unbold (or make some type of legit formatting change) then save.  Even though the column width in datasheet view is technically a formatting aspect, it doesn't register as a change to be saved. If you make another formatting change, it will save column width changes, made in layout view.